# R-Pi regularly becomes unresponsive

Tags: raspbian

Days ago I installed `transmission-daemon` in my R-Pi following [these instructions](http://www.megaleecher.net/Transmission_Torrent_Client_On_Raspberry_Pi#axzz3Wp5BKFgE). Since then it  becomes regularly unresponsive, `ssh`, `git`, `vnc` and all other services become unreachable or return error messages; an hardware reboot is all I am able to do. This is happening at least once a day.

I am not sure this is caused by `transmission-daemon`, since I can not access the system to check error messages and such. What could I do to understand what is happening? Can `transmission-daemon` cause such "crashes"?

**Update**: Some answers to the questions below that deserve a call-out here.

- `transmission-daemon` is logging directly to `/var/log/syslog` [as suggested by goldilocks](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/29469/r-pi-regularly-becomes-unresponsive?noredirect=1#comment38096_29469); however all the messages are of the like "Failed to contact tracker", no other errors or serious warnings are reported.
- `transmission-daemon` is writing to a dedicated USB stick, the SD card is possibly only being used for logging.
- This Pi connects to the internet with a USB WiFi stick.

Comment: How are you powering the Pi? I have experienced this with a poor quality power supply. Are you running a WiFi dongle or other USB devices?

Comment: I have had this Pi for almost an year, used mostly as a Git server without trouble and plugged to the wall socket. I have no reason to suspect an issue with the power supply.

Comment: Have a look through `/var/log/syslog`, *and* whatever log transmission uses, if it is not the system logger.

Comment: The constant read/write of torrenting accelerates wear and tear on the memory card.  Try another card.

Comment: And/or check you're not just [running out of file descriptors](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=file+descriptors+transmission)

Comment: I will increase file descriptors and see if that changes anything.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa I'm having the exact same problem, as soon I turn off transmission everything works normally. Did you fix it?

Comment: @Fex Vrasta No, I never managed to fix this issues, I just removed transmission.